# CSS only working on localhost but not on my other pc

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

I'm working on CI and bootrap for CSS. When I'm developing it on my localhost everything is [running well](https://i.stack.imgur.com/THzRC.png), but when I'm testing on other PC, the bootstrap CSS is [not working well](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8FdR.png)

### **Webpage in my localhost**

[image: Webpage with working CSS]

### **Webpage on my another PC**

[image]

Comment: Please paste your markup. You probably have specified an absolute path that's unique to your first pc.

Comment: There must be some absolute css file path issue due to which css is not loading.

Comment: Can you paste your HTML and css code ?

Answer (score 0):

Your links of stylesheet will be on wrong path or just not right downloaded, look your develope console and check if they are loaded properly.

Answer (score 0):

Use console.log to check ...path is not uploaded properly

Answer (score 0):

I use the helper url in application/config/autoload.php I add

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

With this helper you can use the function `base_url()` of CI and call to a css file only with

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url('css/cssfile.css'); ?>" />
```